# Oracle PL/SQL Select all Columns from Trigger's :NEW

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a trigger that calls a stored procedure when activated, passing :NEW values as a parameter. I have about 40 tables that use the same trigger, and I would like to use the same code for each trigger. Therefore, I am trying to pass all columns of a new row. My code is below and shows what I am attempting to do (however, the problem is that `:NEW.*` is not a valid expression):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "TRIG_TEST_TRIGGER"
AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON TRIG_TEST
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN

    MY_STORED_PROC('Trigger Activated: ' || :NEW.*);

END;
```

Comment: I don't think what you are trying to do is possible unfortunately.  You have to explicitly name each column. I would write a stored procedure that accepts a table name as a parameter and automatically generates the boiler-plate code of the trigger for you by reading from the `user_tables` and `user_tab_columns` dictionary views.  Not sure if you can do better than that.

Comment: I was starting to come to the same conclusion when looking at Oracle's documentation. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you can't.

You could write a procedure that uses dynamic SQL to generate the appropriate trigger code for each table.  Of course, that would require that you re-run the procedure to re-create the trigger every time the table changes.

I'm a bit hard-pressed, though, to imagine what `my_stored_proc` might be doing that it would make sense to pass it a string representing every column from 1 of 40 tables with, presumably, 40 different sets of columns.  If you're writing to a log table, if you want the data from every column, that generally implies that you want to be able to see the evolution of a particular row over time.  But that is extremely hard to do if your log table just has strings in all sorts of different formats from many different tables since you'd constantly have to do things like parsing the string that you logged.

Comment: my_stored_proc is a stored procedure for adding entries to an audit table, which is similar no matter the table, hence the need for reusable code in each trigger. Is there an even better way to create an audit entry on a table being changed?

Comment: @vontell - Why would the audit table be the same for every table?  Either that means that you have 40 tables with basically the same set of columns, which would be a data model issue, or you're throwing everything into a single string and logging that which gets very difficult to work with if you have more than a trivial amount of data.  There are lots of ways to audit changes over time-- Total Recall/ Flashback Data Archive  (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/focus-areas/storage/total-recall-whitepaper-171749.pdf) for example.

Comment: My current solution was to use a string to explain changes, but I agree with your points. Thanks for the suggestions!